# sql server set command with look up from another large table

Tags: sql-server, set

This is probably a simple question, but I pretty new to this. I am trying to set a column in an sql server using the following command:

```
update myTable 
set myCol = a.col 
from table2 as a 
where a.col_1 = col_1 and a.col_2 = col_2;
```

myTable is a bout 150 million rows. and table2 about 300,000 rows. I have indexed table2 properly so the look up is fast. I tried this on a million row separately and it took around 20 secs. But the whole table is taking a very long time, over two days now, and still not finished. I wondered whether there is a better solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) What kind of index do you have on myTable? 2) How much room does your log files have? 3) What kind of logging is enabled for the database?

Comment: Generally, when I have to do updates this big, I usually split it up in smaller chunks. Depending on the system, I do it in 500k-2500k rows at a time.

Comment: Prefix your query with explain to see the plan. add it to your question. But like @AndersUP this might just be one of those things that takes a long time.

Comment: Thanks, I just cancelled the query, it would take sometime to roll back. I would probably split it into 5 million chunks in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the syntax of the `UPDATE` statement should be

```
UPDATE  b 
SET     b.myCol = a.col 
FROM    myTable b
        INNER JOIN table2 a
            ON  a.col_1 = b.col_1 AND
                a.col_2 = b.col_2
```

and you need to supply compound `INDEX` on (col_1, col_2) on both tables.

Comment: I will try this once the query finishes cancelling.

Comment: Hi this worked, but I split the table into chunks of 20 million. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update myTable 
set myTable.myCol = (select a.col from table2 as a 
                     where a.col_1 = myTable.col_1 and 
                     a.col_2 = myTable.col_2
                    )
```

or if this doesn't work its probably because of a problem with true  uniqueness of your join criteria.

Try instead: (This should be whipper snapper fast... but proves your data is most likely in an  inconsistent state.)

```
update myTable 
set myTable.myCol = (select top 1 a.col from table2 as a 
                     where a.col_1 = myTable.col_1 and 
                     a.col_2 = myTable.col_2
                    )
```

Comment: This command doesn't work, it always gives an error that the subquery returns more than one result. I am sure it should return only one, this happens with other tables as well.

Comment: That's why I proposed it.  You may have a problem with choosing a unique enough identifier for your query to function speedily.  You could try top 1, but you probably need to analyze your join criteria and reconsider another update process.

Comment: In table2, I had tested the table for distinct combination of values on col1 and col2. It is the same as the number of rows in the table. So the subquery cannot really return two values unless there is something beneath the bonnet that I don't understand.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense if you have more than one result.  That means your join criteria is not truly atomic between the two tables.